# Grace period для appended answer as supplemental

Tags: дефект, статус-отложено, правки, инструменты-модератора

При использовании действия Преобразовать в правку для двух ответах к вопросу подряд срабатывает grace period и оба ответа вносятся одной правкой, описание которой содержит только один из id ответов.

Пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/969328/revisions

> appended answer 969342 as supplemental

Хотя должно быть 2 ответа - 969337 и 969342:

- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/969337/178988
- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/969342/178988

Comment: О... [возможность перевода добавили](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300580/339911).

Comment: По проблеме: надо или расширять строку, то есть делать список id (либо добавлять такой же текст с новым номером), либо убирать grace-period в таком случае. Но учитывая редкость таких ситуаций делать ничего не будут.

Comment: @JNat what's the meaning of using (status-review) with (status-deferred) simultaneously?

Comment: Oh, oops — I forgot to remove [status-review]. Fixing now